# Рандомный интервал на JS

Tags: javascript, тайминги

Столкнулся с задачкой которую не знаю как решить. Возможно ли на JS сделать рандомный временной интервал? Например нужно кликать по элементу в диапазоне времени от 45 до 80 сек, чтоб каждый клик был с разным интервалом, 45сек, 55сек, 71сек, 68сек, 47сек и так далее в рамках установленного диапазона и чтоб интервал друг за другом не повторялся, 44сек, 44сек.

Comment: Возможно. *(6 символов нужно...)*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял задачу.

```js
//# Тут мы создаём рандомный интервал в диапазоне
let RRh = 0; // Храним предыдущее значение
function RandomRange(a,b) { // Функция принимает минимальное и максимальное значение
  let c = Math.floor(Math.random() * (b - a + 1)) + a; // Получаем рандомное число
  return c !== RRh ? RRh = c : RandomRange(a,b); // Сверяем его с прошлым, если совпало то ништяк, если нет то всё по новой.
}

console.time('click'); // Для наблюдения, сколько был интервал

//# Это для имуляции 
let elem = document.querySelector('#click'), // Берём элемент по которому будем кликать
    timer = setTimeout(function tick() { // Тут рекурсивный таймер
  elem.click(); // Который кликает каждый раз в заданный интервал
  timer = setTimeout(tick, RandomRange(5,15) * 1000); // Интервал будет рандомный от 5 до 15 секунд
}, RandomRange(5,15) * 1000);


//# А тут чисто визуализация того, что клик действительно происходит
elem.addEventListener('click', function(e) { 
  console.timeEnd('click'); // Для наблюдения, сколько был интервал
  let $self = e.target;
  $self.style.cssText = 'border-color: red; transform: scale(1.25);'
  $self.innerText = 'CLICKED';
  setTimeout(function() {
    $self.style.cssText = '';
    $self.innerText = 'element';
    console.time('click'); // Для наблюдения, сколько был интервал
  }, 750);
});
```

```css
#click {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 2px solid gray;
  padding: .5em;
  margin: 30px;
}

.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 22px !important;}
```

```html
<div id="click">element</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Для генерирования случайного числа в диапазоне достаточно запомнить эту «идиому»:

[Getting a random integer between two values, inclusive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random#getting_a_random_integer_between_two_values_inclusive)

Но чтобы числа не повторялись, нужно добавлять вспомогательную структуру данных (например, [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set)), чтобы хранить в ней использованные числа, проверять и отбраковываеть уже встречавшиеся.

Например, этот код использует функцию, которая создаёт генератор случайных чисел с привязкой к такой структуре данных. Когда структура заполняется всеми возможными числами диапазона, она очищается и перебор начинается снова.

```js
function createRandomGenerator(min, max) {
  const usedRandoms = new Set();
  const limit = max - min + 1;

  return function getRandom() {
    if (usedRandoms.size === limit) usedRandoms.clear();

    let random;

    while (usedRandoms.has(random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min))) ;

    usedRandoms.add(random);
    return random;
  };
}

const getRandomOneTen = createRandomGenerator(1, 10);

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) console.log(getRandomOneTen());
console.log('----------');
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) console.log(getRandomOneTen());
```

Думаю, вы сможете приспособить этот пример к вашему случаю.

Единственное что — если диапазон чисел будет очень большой, функция со временем может нагружать процессор в поисках ещё не использованного числа, отбраковывая всё больше попыток. Тогда стоит вынести её в worker или добавить небольшие таймауты уже в неё, чтобы она не мешала интерактивности страницы.